# Angular Update from 7 to 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I have recently upgraded my angular from 7 to 11, i am now getting this error "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\node_modules\has\src'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry". however when i check the package.json i can see the main entry

[image]

> ```
> {   "_from": "has@^1.0.3",   "_id": "has@1.0.3",   "_inBundle": false,   "_integrity":
> ```
>
> "sha512-f2dvO0VU6Oej7RkWJGrehjbzMAjFp5/VKPp5tTpWIV4JHHZK1/BxbFRtf/siA2SWTe09caDmVtYYzWEIbBS4zw==",
> "_location": "/has",   "_phantomChildren": {},   "_requested": {
> "type": "range",
> "registry": true,
> "raw": "has@^1.0.3",
> "name": "has",
> "escapedName": "has",
> "rawSpec": "^1.0.3",
> "saveSpec": null,
> "fetchSpec": "^1.0.3"   },   "_requiredBy": [
> "/es-abstract",
> "/is-regex"   ],   "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/has/-/has-1.0.3.tgz",   "_shasum":
> "722d7cbfc1f6aa8241f16dd814e011e1f41e8796",   "_spec": "has@^1.0.3",
> "_where": "C:\Users\projects-app\node_modules\is-regex",
> "author": {
> "name": "Thiago de Arruda",
> "email": "tpadilha84@gmail.com"   },   "bugs": {
> "url": "https://github.com/tarruda/has/issues"   },   "bundleDependencies": false,   "contributors": [
> {
> "name": "Jordan Harband",
> "email": "ljharb@gmail.com",
> "url": "http://ljharb.codes"
> }   ],   "dependencies": {
> "function-bind": "^1.1.1"   },   "deprecated": false,   "description": "Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call shortcut",
> "devDependencies": {
> "@ljharb/eslint-config": "^12.2.1",
> "eslint": "^4.19.1",
> "tape": "^4.9.0"   },   "engines": {
> "node": ">= 0.4.0"   },   "homepage": "https://github.com/tarruda/has",   "license": "MIT",   "licenses": [
> {
> "type": "MIT",
> "url": "https://github.com/tarruda/has/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT"
> }   ],   "main": "./src",   "name": "has",   "repository": {
> "type": "git",
> "url": "git://github.com/tarruda/has.git"   },   "scripts": {
> "lint": "eslint .",
> "pretest": "npm run lint",
> "test": "tape test"   },   "version": "1.0.3" }

I would appreciate any guidance on this matter. i tried npm update other commands but still having the same issue.

Comment: The "has" dependency https://www.npmjs.com/package/has was updated last 3 years ago. I doubt it is compatible to angular 10. I recommend to remove it and replace the occurences by `hasOwnProperty` calls.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm you mean replace the "name": "has" to "name":"hasOwnProperty" in the package.json file?

Comment: No, I mean remove "has" dependency which includes to remove it from package.json. The "has" lib provides a possibility to use "has" instead of "hasOwnProperties" in code. You need to change those code snippets to remove the usage of the lib.